# hibernate will not insert value of foreign key id on persist

Tags: hibernate

I have 2 classes, Student and Class. Each Student can be part of one Class only.

I am trying to insert Student using the following code

```
            for (Class cls : classList) {
            if (cls.getId().getClassId() == selectedClassId.intValue()) {
                selectedStudent.setClass(cls);
            }
        }
        HibernateUtil.beginTransaction();
        StudentHome stuhome = new StudentHome();
        stuhome.persist(selectedStudent);
        HibernateUtil.commitTransaction();
```

But for some reason Hibernate is not inserting the classId field in the Student table.

Below is the SQL output I got from Hibernate

```
Hibernate: 
select
    class_.ClassId,
    class_.EntityId,
    class_.ClassName as ClassName2_ 
from
    school.class102 class_ 
where
    class_.ClassId=? 
    and class_.EntityId=?

Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    school.student102
    (StudentId, ParentId, RouteId, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName, DoB, DoJ, DoL, Status, RegistrationId, EntityId) 
values
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Asyou can see, classId is clearly missing from the insert statement. I am not sure whu Hibernate has not included the classId in the insert statement.

EntityId and RegistrationId is the PK for Student and
EntityId and ClassId is the PK for Class. 
There is a foreign key relationship with (EntityId, ClassId) in both the tables.
The insert is attemped thru a view with a predefined EntityId

What could be the issue?

Below are the mappings

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Student" table="student104" catalog="school">
    <composite-id name="id" class="studentId">
        <key-property name="registrationId" type="int">
            <column name="RegistrationId" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="entityId" type="int">
            <column name="EntityId" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <many-to-one name="class" class="class" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
        <column name="ClassId" />
        <column name="EntityId" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="studentId" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="StudentId" />
    </property>
    <property name="parentId" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="ParentId" />
    </property>
    <property name="routeId" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="RouteId" />
    </property>
    <property name="firstName" type="string">
        <column name="FirstName" length="45" />
    </property>
    <property name="lastName" type="string">
        <column name="LastName" length="45" />
    </property>
    <property name="middleName" type="string">
        <column name="MiddleName" length="45" />
    </property>
    <property name="doB" type="date">
        <column name="DoB" length="10" />
    </property>
    <property name="doJ" type="date">
        <column name="DoJ" length="10" />
    </property>
    <property name="doL" type="date">
        <column name="DoL" length="10" />
    </property>
    <property name="status" type="string">
        <column name="Status" length="45" />
    </property>
</class>
```

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="class" table="class102" catalog="school">
    <composite-id name="id" class="classId">
        <key-property name="classId" type="int">
            <column name="ClassId" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="entityId" type="int">
            <column name="EntityId" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="className" type="string">
        <column name="ClassName" length="45" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <set name="students" table="student104" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="ClassId" />
            <column name="EntityId" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="student" />
    </set>
</class>
```

Comment: @Pokuri Thanks for taking time, I have added the mappings now.

Comment: Hello, I have exactly the same problem. Have you be able to solve this issue? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your mapping of Student

```
<many-to-one name="class" class="class" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
        <column name="ClassId" />
        <column name="EntityId" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
```

you said not to insert or update the relation into student. If you think once student assigned to a class cannot be modified then set `update="false" insert="true"` else can be modified later then set `update="true" insert="true"`. And both attribute values are by default(if you omit them from mapping) `true` only.

Comment: I tried setting both to 'true' but got a Mapping exception. it says..Repeated column in mapping for entity: student column: EntityId (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false") .. it looks like a problem with having a composite PK on both the tables .. I am not sure thou.